# URL encoding - Opera versus Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, opera

I am learning Russian language, so I go thru lots of Russian language pages.
Sometimes I want to keep an URL in my notepad.

There is a curious phenomenon at this moment :

If I go to a certain page using Chrome, the "copied" URL is

(1) >>>    https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9

But is I go to the very same place with Opera, and "copy" the URL, I get

(2) >>>    [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Кощей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Obviously, in my Notepad the (2ns) URL looks lots more "readable".

How can I get Chrome to display URLs using Russian characters and not in URL encoding ?

Tx.

Comment: Pardon my pettiness, but that's [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), not UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the open-source extension
[Copy Unicode URLs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-unicode-urls/fnbbfiapefhkicjhecnoepbijhanpkjp?hl=en),
described as:

> Copy Unicode URLs to clipboard without nasty percent-encodings or
> Punycode! Annoyed by all the converting of unicode chars in urls while
> copy-pasting? Copy urls with this extension to preserve unicode
> untouched. No more percent-encoding, no more punycode.
>
> Use Alt+U shortcut or click the icon to copy URL from address bar.
> Right-click extension icon to access options.

I tested it on your link and it worked perfectly.